# Test peewee fn.rand error

Tags: python, peewee, flask-peewee

I'm writing the API tests and when I use peewee function fn.Rand() I get this error:

```
cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
OperationalError: no such function: Rand
```

My code is:

```
query = Questions.select().order_by(fn.Rand()).limit(limit)
list = [ob.as_json() for ob in query]
```

Any ideia how to resolve?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database, the function may be called "Random". Try changing your code to `fn.Random()`.

Answer (score 0):

## Postgresql and Sqlite use the *Random* function:

```
# Pick 5 lucky winners:
LotteryNumber.select().order_by(fn.Random()).limit(5)
```

## MySQL uses *Rand*:

```
# Pick 5 lucky winners:
LotterNumber.select().order_by(fn.Rand()).limit(5)
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#getting-random-records) anyway....